# Flask handler starts twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

When starting Flask, I get the `handler started` message twice, even before any request is made. What is the redundant process and how to fix this?

```
 * Serving Flask app "app.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with windowsapi reloader
------------>>> handler started
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 519-729-899
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
------------>>> handler started
```

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from frontend.handler import handler
   
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(handler)


@app.route('/flask_alive')
def requestAlive():
    return 'Flast is alive'
```

`handler.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify, abort
import pprint
import datetime
   
handler = Blueprint('handler', __name__)
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

print('------------>>> handler started')


@handler.route('/visualcode/py/<url>', methods=['POST'])
@check_auth
def process(url):
    ...................
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think its an error it always happens to me when ever i user the `debug=True`.